# SubmitOnChanges / InsertOnSubmit / DeleteOnSubmit are not detected

Tags: asp.net-mvc

SubmitOnChanges / InsertOnSubmit / DeleteOnSubmit are not detected in ASP.NET MVC4. What should  I do? Please help!﻿

Answer (score 0):

`SubmitChanges`, `InsertOnSubmit` and `DeleteOnSubmit` are methods of the `DataContext` class and `Table<Entity>` class of Linq2Sql respectively.

If you are using Linq2Sql in MVC4 and have an instance of the `DataContext` class and the `Table<Entity>` classes (for each of your tables), you'll have these methods available to you.

Comment: How do I know what I'm using and how to use Linq2Sql. I'm new to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @xxxx It is an older data access framework. If you are using visual studio, you should be able to setup linq2sql easily but since you don't know what it is, i'm not sure if that would be a good idea. Might be better to read a couple of resources on the subject first. Microsoft recommends Entity Framework as the preferred data access framework.